# Error during VSTS Account creation Azure using Azure Arm templates

Tags: python, azure-rm-template

I am trying to create VSTS account on Azure using Arm Template.
I am using msrestazure python module for deploying the templates.
But i am getting the following error :

> Azure Error: DeploymentFailed
>           Message: At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see
>   https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.
>           Exception Details:
>                   Error Code: BadRequest
>                   Message: {
>             "code": "BadArgument",
>             "message": "The string must have at least one character.\r\nParameter name: accountName",
>             "target": "LegacyGetOrCreateBindPendingIdentity"
>           }
>                   Target: None

I am providing the value for parameter accountName but still it says that the string must have at least one character.Also i am able to create account using UI. Please help :)

Comment: Share your ARM template and whatever commands you're running to deploy it. The error is pretty clear, there's a parameter called `accountName` that you're not specifying.

Comment: my arm Template:-
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {},
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "Crivs123",
      "type": "microsoft.visualstudio/account",
      "location": "centralus",
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
      "properties": {
      "operationType": "Create",
      "accountName" : "Crivs123"
           },
      "resources": [
      ]
    }
  ]
}Same template when run from portal is running successfully

@DanielMann

Answer (score 0):

The message is not clear, but it could be that your user doesn't have enough permission; no guests are allowed to create Account.

You can validate that you are a member by going to the *Users and groups* section

[image]

Comment: But with the same user the template is successfully deployed from portal

Comment: anybody can you help please?

Comment: @NarinderVerma, when you say deployed in the portal, you mean using the Cloud terminal, or creating the resources in the portal?

Comment: creating the resource in portal using json template